# Issue using Dropbox API in Python to access shared link and download images

Tags: python, dropbox-api

So, as the title say, I am trying to download images from a public shared link because, when I am trying to download it with either curl/wget or the download button the file gets corrupted. There are 7000 images and in total it is about 2GB.

Here is my code

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("token")

dbx.users_get_current_account()


url = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/shared_link?dl=0"
shared_link = dropbox.files.SharedLink(url=url)

result = dbx.files_list_folder(path="", shared_link=shared_link)
file_list = []

def process_entries(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
            link = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url, path="/"+entry.name)
            print(entry.name)
            print(link)
            file_list.append([entry.name])

process_entries(result.entries)

while result.has_more:
    result = dbx.files_list_folder_continue(result.cursor)
    process_entries(result.entries)

print(len(file_list))
```

The list shows correctly in length that there are 7000 images. Though, either I am doing something wrong, or I can't figure out how I can download those files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[The `sharing_get_shared_link_file` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.sharing_get_shared_link_file) returns a tuple of `(dropbox.sharing.SharedLinkMetadata, requests.models.Response)`. The first item is the metadata, and the second item is the response object where you can access the actual file content.

Your code is currently just saving that tuple to one variable. If you want to download the file data, you can do something like this instead:

```
metadata, res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file(url, path="/"+entry.name)
with open(entry.name, "wb") as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```